# Parsing a nested list

Tags: python, json, parsing

So I have a nested list that I need to parse through and manipulate the contents of. I am getting this data from the Merriam Webster dictionary API

Here is what that JSON data looks like:

```
[
  {
    "meta": {
      "id": "trellis:2",
      "uuid": "3a22ee1d-f552-4836-bd2a-3e6b2fe11884",
      "sort": "200364400",
      "src": "collegiate",
      "section": "alpha",
      "stems": [
        "trellis",
        "trellised",
        "trellises",
        "trellising"
      ],
      "offensive": false
    },
    "hom": 2,
    "hwi": {
      "hw": "trellis"
    },
    "fl": "verb",
    "ins": [
      {
        "if": "trel*lised"
      },
      {
        "if": "trel*lis*ing"
      },
      {
        "if": "trel*lis*es"
      }
    ],
    "def": [
      {
        "vd": "transitive verb",
        "sseq": [
          [
            [
              "sense",
              {
                "sn": "1",
                "dt": [
                  [
                    "text",
                    "{bc}to provide with a trellis"
                  ]
                ],
                "sdsense": {
                  "sd": "especially",
                  "dt": [
                    [
                      "text",
                      "{bc}to train (a plant, such as a vine) on a trellis"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              "sense",
              {
                "sn": "2",
                "dt": [
                  [
                    "text",
                    "{bc}to cross or interlace on or through {bc}{sx|interweave||}"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    "date": "15th century{ds||1||}",
    "shortdef": [
      "to provide with a trellis; especially : to train (a plant, such as a vine) on a trellis",
      "to cross or interlace on or through : interweave"
    ]
  },
  {
    "meta": {
      "id": "trellis:1",
      "uuid": "db2e1190-dd93-45f3-831c-9e9536aab601",
      "sort": "200364300",
      "src": "collegiate",
      "section": "alpha",
      "stems": [
        "trellis",
        "trellised",
        "trellises"
      ],
      "offensive": false
    },
    "hom": 1,
    "hwi": {
      "hw": "trel*lis",
      "prs": [
        {
          "mw": "ˈtre-ləs",
          "sound": {
            "audio": "trelli01",
            "ref": "c",
            "stat": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "fl": "noun",
    "def": [
      {
        "sseq": [
          [
            [
              "sense",
              {
                "sn": "1",
                "dt": [
                  [
                    "text",
                    "{bc}a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              "sense",
              {
                "sn": "2",
                "dt": [
                  [
                    "text",
                    "{bc}a construction (such as a summerhouse) chiefly of latticework"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              "sense",
              {
                "sn": "3",
                "dt": [
                  [
                    "text",
                    "{bc}an arrangement that forms or gives the effect of a lattice "
                  ],
                  [
                    "vis",
                    [
                      {
                        "t": "a {wi}trellis{/wi} of interlacing streams"
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
    "uros": [
      {
        "ure": "trel*lised",
        "prs": [
          {
            "mw": "ˈtre-ləst",
            "sound": {
              "audio": "trelli02",
              "ref": "c",
              "stat": "1"
            }
          }
        ],
        "fl": "adjective"
      }
    ],
    "art": {
      "artid": "trellis",
      "capt": "trellis 1"
    },
    "et": [
      [
        "text",
        "Middle English {it}trelis{/it}, from Anglo-French {it}treleis{/it}, from Old French {it}treille{/it} arbor, from Latin {it}trichila{/it} summerhouse"
      ]
    ],
    "date": "14th century{ds||1||}",
    "shortdef": [
      "a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants",
      "a construction (such as a summerhouse) chiefly of latticework",
      "an arrangement that forms or gives the effect of a lattice"
    ]
  }
]
```

And here is what I want to change the data to:
I am extracting the definitions from `shortdef`

```
Definition (Entry 1/2):
1: to provide with a trellis; especially : to train (a plant, such as a vine) on a trellis

2: to cross or interlace on or through : interweave1: a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants

Definition (Entry 2/2):
1: a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants

2: a construction (such as a summerhouse) chiefly of latticework

3: an arrangement that forms or gives the effect of a lattice
```

My current code below is only able to parse non nested lists and I am struggling to figure out how to modify it to be able to parse nested lists:

```
defin_formatted = ""
word_defin = []
for i in data:
    word_defin.append(i['shortdef'])

for group in word_defin:
    if len(group) > 1:
        result = []
        for i,v in enumerate(group):
            result.append("**{}:** {}".format(i+1, v))
        group = '\n\n'.join(result)
        
    else:
        group = group[0]
    defin_formatted = defin_formatted + group
```

This code produces this output:

```
1: to provide with a trellis; especially : to train (a plant, such as a vine) on a trellis

2: to cross or interlace on or through : interweave1: a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants

2: a construction (such as a summerhouse) chiefly of latticework

3: an arrangement that forms or gives the effect of a lattice
```

This is very close so what is intended but flawed

Comment: The problem is, you haven't given us the whole story.  You're showing a pair of lists, but there's nothing that shows us where `'shortdef'` comes into things.  What does the original JSON look like?

Comment: yeah, of course, here it is: https://pastebin.com/PKTzGgzh

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a **small** example input data and the corresponding expected result. As it stands, the question is overly verbose and yet incomplete. Try to boil it down to the essential and keep it self-contained (no reference needed to pastebin).

Comment: @TimRoberts I attached the json to the Pastebin above

Comment: @PierreD Better now?

Comment: Not really. I've read this three times now, I still have no idea what you want or what the problem is. We don't know what your data is, etc. Try a minimalistic setup code to describe what `data` contains (something we can copy paste and exhibits the problem you are facing).

Comment: I am trying to manipulate the data from the original json file to be formatted like I demonstrate, I've tried the following code but it only works for lists that are not nested

Comment: Did you read and understand the page about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Those first three bullet points are really important for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243704/discussion-between-dan-a-and-pierre-d).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach this. First, an extraction into a structure more amenable to the transformations we want to do, and second, the transformations/decorations themselves. I would build an actual string with all of a definition (or multiple ones) as the last step.

```py
import warnings
from collections import defaultdict

data2 = defaultdict(dict)
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    try:
        key, num = d['meta']['id'].split(':', 1)
        defs = d['shortdef']
        data2[key][num] = defs
    except KeyError as e:
        warnings.warn(f'caught in data[{i}]: {e!r}')

data2 = {k: [defs for _, defs in sorted(v.items())] for k, v in data2.items()}
```

At this point, we have a structure with the information we want:

```py
>>> data2
{'trellis': [['a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants',
   'a construction (such as a summerhouse) chiefly of latticework',
   'an arrangement that forms or gives the effect of a lattice'],
  ['to provide with a trellis; especially : to train (a plant, such as a vine) on a trellis',
   'to cross or interlace on or through : interweave']]}
```

Then, we can do some transformations (all comprehensions) to decorate the definitions with "(Entry i of n)" and the numbering of the examples.

```py
nested_lines = [
    (f'Definition of {k} (Entry {i} of {len(v)})',
     [f'{j}: {txt}' for j, txt in enumerate(defs, 1)])
    for k, v in data2.items()
    for i, defs in enumerate(v, 1)
]
```

We now have:

```py
>>> nested_lines
[('Definition of trellis (Entry 1 of 2)',
  ['1: a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants',
   '2: a construction (such as a summerhouse) chiefly of latticework',
   '3: an arrangement that forms or gives the effect of a lattice']),
 ('Definition of trellis (Entry 2 of 2)',
  ['1: to provide with a trellis; especially : to train (a plant, such as a vine) on a trellis',
   '2: to cross or interlace on or through : interweave'])]
```

And now, if we want to print these definitions, say, we would do:

```py
text = '\n\n'.join(['\n'.join([k, '', '\n'.join(v)]) for k, v in nested_lines])

>>> print(text)
Definition of trellis (Entry 1 of 2)

1: a frame of latticework used as a screen or as a support for climbing plants
2: a construction (such as a summerhouse) chiefly of latticework
3: an arrangement that forms or gives the effect of a lattice

Definition of trellis (Entry 2 of 2)

1: to provide with a trellis; especially : to train (a plant, such as a vine) on a trellis
2: to cross or interlace on or through : interweave
```

Comment: The API I am using to extract the JSON data from is the Merriam webster dictionary, and with your code, the data is not parsed correctly, and only works for several cases. Try for example parsing something like this: https://pastebin.com/SX7hxEge

Comment: I have also been working on improving my own code and have came up with this. I updated the question with my code which I just have to format and I am having some trouble doing so